# Force React component to return same Object with javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

Is there any way to force React component to return same object  with javascript

for example i have the object card and i want to force my react component to return the Card Object (some thing like inheritance in java )

export const Card = (rank, suit) => { return { rank: rank, suit: suit } }